# How can i target elements in another array via .filter()

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to return the values in argument[0] that are not equal to the values of arguments[1] and so on.

Ive created a variable 'let argArr' that holds the values of the arguments after the first, Im trying to understand why in my .filter() i cannot target 'let argArr'?

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  let argArr = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    argArr.push(arguments[i])
  }

  return arr.filter(i => i !== argArr)
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing an `arr` array's element to the `argArr` what is wrong.
The right way is to check if element is inside `argArr` and filter if yes.

`return arr.filter(i => !argArr.includes(i))`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `arguments` explicitly specify the array as the first argument, and then use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to gather all the remaining arguments into an array. Then use `filter` to return only those elements in the array that are not in the `rest` array.

```js
function destroyer(arr, ...rest) {
  return arr.filter(el => !rest.includes(el));
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use spread operator to treat arguments as normal array

```js
function foo() {
    return [...arguments].filter(el => el);
}
console.log(foo(1,2,3))
```

Comment: You should link to the [spread syntax documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).